# Using a vector function on a node member

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, nodes

I'm writing a program in C++ where I take in a line from a txt file and stick it into a `vector<string> data` that is within a struct (I'm making a linked list of each individual line). Technically I have a loop set up that will break up the words from the sentence I'm taking in, and pushing them into the vector one by one.

The issue I've ran into is when I try getting the vector size via

```
int size;
size = current->data.size();
```

Current being a node. I get both an implicit conversion warning and a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)".

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong? Is it just not possible to code something like that? Should I just create a counter variable to keep track of how many words are being placed into the vector? And what would be the best programming practice to go about achieving this?

Here is my main() file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "SkipGram.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string file;
    ifstream inFile;
    vector<string> sentence;
    string line;
    SkipGram control;
    int skip;
    int gram;

    cout << "Please enter file name:\n";
    cin >> file;
    inFile.open(file);

    while(!inFile.is_open()){   //makes sure we get a working file
        cout << "Error reading in file. Please try again.";
        cin >> file;
        inFile.open(file);
    }

    cout << "Please enter how many words you want skipped and the amount of grams:";
    cin >> skip >> gram;

    while(!inFile.eof()){
        getline(inFile, line);
        control.convert(line);
    }

    control.skipGramFunc(skip, gram);
    control.printSkipGram();

    return 0;



}
```

Here is my .hpp file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class SkipGram{
public:
    SkipGram();
    void convert(string line);
    void skipGramFunc(int skip, int gram);
    void printSkipGram();

private:
    typedef struct sentence{
        vector<string> data;
        vector<string> result;
        int position;
        sentence* next;
    }* sentencePtr;

    sentencePtr first;
    sentencePtr current;
    int amount;
};
```

Here is my .cpp file

```
#include "SkipGram.hpp"

using namespace std;

SkipGram::SkipGram(){
    first = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    amount = 0;
}

void SkipGram::convert(string line){
    // go word by word through sentence and create a vector out of it
    // add into the sentence list
    sentencePtr newSentence = new struct sentence;


    if(first == NULL){
        current = newSentence;
        first = newSentence;
        amount++;
        newSentence->position = amount;
    }else {
        current = newSentence;
        amount++;
        newSentence->position = amount;
    }

        string word;
        int length = line.length();
        int i = 0;
        int front = 0;
        int temp;

        while( i <= length){
            temp = line.find(" ");
            if( temp == -1){
                break; //catches when sentence is done with
            }
            word = line.substr(front, temp);
            newSentence->data.push_back(word);
            temp++;
            line = line.erase(front, temp);
        } //END OF WHILE

    }



void SkipGram::skipGramFunc(int skip, int gram){
    // goes through word vector and rearranges them
    if(gram == 1){
        cout << "Need more than one gram!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(skip == 0 || gram == 0){
        cout << "Input cannot be 0!";
    }

    int size;
    int temp;
    int tempAmount = amount;

    current = first;
    skip++;

    while( tempAmount != 0){ // while loop goes through all the sentences

        size = current->data.size();
        size = size - skip; // size here essentially becomes a marker to find out where to stop the loop

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){ // for loop goes through all the words

            for(int j = 0; j < gram; j++){ // this loop checks to see if we got the right number of grams
                if(j == 0){ // are we on the first gram
                    current->result.push_back(current->data.at(i));
                }else { // we want skipped gram
                    temp = i + skip;
                    current->result.push_back(current->data.at(temp));
                } // END OF IF

            }// END OF GRAM IF

            current->result.push_back(",");

        }//END OF WORD FOR

        current = current->next;
        tempAmount--;
    }//END OF WHILE

}// END OF FUNCTION

void SkipGram::printSkipGram(){


    int tempAmount = amount;

    current = first;

    while(tempAmount != 0){
        int size = current->data.size();

        for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
            cout << current->data.at(i);
        };

    }//END OF WHILE

}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `current` and `data`? I'm assuming `data` is a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], which includes a main(), and all includes, so that a member can copy and paste into an IDE.

Comment: Yes data is a vector and current is a struct. I also added in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign to `next`, but you do read it. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing a value of uninitialized object.

Comment: OH! Good catch! Thank you so much!